# Call two function onValueChange in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I call function `DoMath` when TextInput is changed?

```
state = {
  foo: 2,
  bar: 3,
  Total: 0,
}

DoMath = () =>{
    var foo = this.state.foo;
    var bar = this.state.bar;

    this.state.Total= foo + bar;
    this.setState({Total: this.state.Total})     
}

<TextInput
   onChangeText={(foo) => this.setState({foo})}
   value={this.state.foo}
   selectTextOnFocus>
</TextInput>
```

I tried doing `onChangeText={(foo) => this.setState({foo}); DoMath;}` but it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap the body of arrow functions with more than one statement in braces. If you just do `onChangeText={(foo) => this.setState({foo}); DoMath;}`, that'll be interpreted as two statements:

What JS sees is:

```js
onChangeText={(foo) => { return this.setState({foo}); }; DoMath;}
```

So `DoMath` gets evaluated when the component is created, but does not get ran when the component's text changes.

Change it to:

```js
onChangeText={(foo) => { this.setState({foo}); DoMath(); } }
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you marked correct might cause you issues, setState is async and `DoMath` relies on that updated value. setState offers a callback that will be ran after state gets updated so you will have the updated values when you invoke `DoMath`:

```
handleChangeText = foo => this.setState({ foo }, this.DoMath)
...
...
onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
```

Also never do this:

```
this.state.Total= foo + bar;

this.setState({Total: this.state.Total})

//Do this
const Total= foo + bar;

this.setState({ Total })
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be like this:

```
DoMath = ()=> {
 console.log(foo)
}

onChangeText={(foo=> {this.setState({ foo});},() => this.DoMath())}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution here would be to use the prop of TextInput called as onEndEditing

```
<TextInput
   onChangeText={(foo) => this.setState({foo})}
   onEndEditing={this.DoMath()}
   value={this.state.foo}
   selectTextOnFocus
/>
```

You can change the usage according to your own usecase